# Deletting nested document from an array of fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, nestjs

I have an array of products in a mongo document and I have been try to get one product and delete it, but I haven't been able to do that.

```js
async deleteOneStoreProduct(storeId: string, productId: string) {
    console.log(storeId, productId);
    const storetofind = await this.storeModel.findOne({
      storeId,
    });
    if (!storetofind) {
      throw new Error('Store not found');
    }

    const store = await this.storeModel.updateOne(
      {
        storeId,
      },
      {
        $pull: {
          products: { 'product.productId': productId },
        },
      },
    );
    return store;
    // const store = await this.storeModel.updateOne(
    //   {
    //     storeId: storeId,
    //   },
    //   {
    //     $pull: { products: { 'product.productId': productId } },
    //   },
    // );
    console.log(store);
    if (!store) {
      throw new Error('Store not found');
    }
    return store;
  }
```

Here is my schema Example, I have the productId inside the product which is an object in an array of products.

```
{
_id:"656b0bb194d0010639157793",
storeName:"Muzardemoses Tech",
storeId:"Muzardemoses Tech_198",
isProfileVerified:"false",
isProfileCompleted:"true",
companyPhone:"09134452294",
storeAddress:"77, Oremeji Street , off EKoro junction, opp NNPC Abule-Egba",
storeDescription:"Buy Your gadget at affordable price",
storeLogo:"https://res.cloudinary.com/fundrit-files/image/upload/v1701514159/bnpl/…",
storeCategory:[],
storeState:"Lagos",
storeLGA:"Alimosho",
storeEmail:"richardebrain21@gmail.com",
storeWebsite:"https://richardadebayo.tech",
__v:0,
products:[ 

{
    "storeId": "Muzardemoses Tech_198",
    "companyPhone": "09131449283",
    "storeAddress": "77, Oremeji Street , off EKoro junction, opp NNPC Abule-Egba",
    "storeName": "Muzardemoses Tech",
    "storeLogo": "https://res.cloudinary.com/fundrit-files/image/upload/v1701514159/bnpl/jgklrlhfamxrzxlj13td.jpg",
    "product": {
        "productName": "Macbookpro 2017",
        "productDescription": "MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports)",
        "productPrice": "1500000",
        "productCategory": "Laptops",
        "productCondition": "New",
        "features": "",
        "productBrand": "Apple",
        "productImages": [
            "https://res.cloudinary.com/fundrit-files/image/upload/v1701784329/bnpl/lm8j5caswk9la2kjterh.jpg",
            "https://res.cloudinary.com/fundrit-files/image/upload/v1701784330/bnpl/rkgoawk1dkc3hqtvtlgh.jpg",
            "https://res.cloudinary.com/fundrit-files/image/upload/v1701784330/bnpl/nlbuyqvakofe8yqp7rrd.jpg",
            "https://res.cloudinary.com/fundrit-files/image/upload/v1701784331/bnpl/thkfyndqklp6en0phfuz.jpg"
        ],
        "productId": "Macbookpro_2017_1701784331869",
        "createdAt": "2023-12-05T13:52:11.869Z"
    },
},
{}
]
}
```

Note: the storedId works for finding the desired store.

here is my response, it only matched but does not modify which it should.

```
{
    "acknowledged": true,
    "modifiedCount": 0,
    "upsertedId": null,
    "upsertedCount": 0,
    "matchedCount": 1
}
```

Comment: I am not sure about your db schema model but can you try this `$pull: { products: { 'product.$.productId': productId }`

Comment: Can you post your schema to  confirm that in your schema `storeId` is of type `String` and that `productId` is of type `String` because you are typing them as such in the `deleteOneStoreProduct` function.

Comment: The commented out version of `$pull` is [working fine](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EuUzvydSmnr). Check the correctness of arguments that you are supplying (i.e. `storeId` and `productId`) to the update function.

Comment: @ray , it didn't work using updateOne

Comment: @Richardebrain what is *it didn't work*? The data is not matched and updated? Some error thrown? If it is the former, as I said, you might want to check if your parameter can correctly locate the entry you want to update first.

Comment: @ray. the entry did match the particular document , but deleting like that didn't work ,i had to pass the productId to the first level instead of nesting it in the product object before i was able to delete it.